# Can only set one of `children` or `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to set the inner HTML of an alert div, but receiving the error message : `Can only set one of 'children' or props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML'.`

Why does this happen ?

```
function alertContent(alert) { return {__html: alert.text} }

const Alerts = ({ alerts=[{level: 'warning', text:'<p>Warning message!</p>'}], onDismiss }) => (
    <div className="alerts">
        {alerts.map(alert =>
            <Alert
                bsStyle={alert.level}
                key={alert.id}
                onDismiss={onDismiss}
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={alertContent(alert)} 
                ></Alert>
        )}
    </div>
)
```

Comment: I'm confused at your implementation. I would just pass in the "alert.text" as a prop in "<Alert txt={alert.text}" , and then in your Alert component, do the dangerouslySetInnerHtml, ala __html: this.props.txt

Comment: Try using a self-closing tag (<Alert props props props />) instead of an opening and a closing tag. It's possible those still count as children in a way.

Comment: @jamesemanon The "Alert" component comes from the react-bootstrap library, so I can't change it unfortunately.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This happens because `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` can only be applied to one element. In your case, `<Alert/>` is a complex element made up of multiple children. That being said, the BS Alert component does accept HTML:

```
<Alert bsStyle="warning">
  <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Best check yo self, you're not looking too good.
</Alert>
```

or

```
<Alert bsStyle="warning">
  <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={alertContent(alert)} />
</Alert>
```

Comment: I don't get how this is the accepted answer. I mean, yes you are correct that it doesn't accept `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, but stating that it fortunately accepts HTML doesn't mean much since the reason for using that property is obviously because the text is coming from elsewhere

Comment: Then just replace the example html code with your variable.

Comment: I don't understand. If you do `const someString = '<strong>Test</strong>` and `<Alert>{someString}</Alert>` then you will just get the encoded HTML tags as a string. This is often what would happen if you had your strings coming from a database, or the like. So DSIHTML would be required.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I should have expanded my answer to add the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to a tag within the alert.

Comment: Nice one, thanks! Glad I wasn't losing my mind there ;)

Answer (score 74):

I had this error message in a react application.

My issue was I had code as below

```
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html:stringContainingHtml}}> </p>
```

My issue was the space in the `<p> </p>` tags - since html gets injected inside these tags the space was causing an issue as it wasn't empty.

Hope this might help some people.

Comment: Helped me! I had a placeholder left over in there. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up just using self closing tags to avoid the space.

Comment: That is a much cleaner idea for JSX. Good call.

Comment: fixed my issue too, tks

Answer (score 5):

Solution, You have to make a separate component to render element in which you are using dangerously set.....

For Example:

```
const RenderHTML = (props) => (<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:props.HTML}}></span>)



YourData.map((d,i) => {
    return <RenderHTML  HTML={d.YOUR_HTML} />
})
```

Comment: That was the secret for me.  Always put dangerouslySetInnerHTML inside a span and then hand that around, instead of putting dangerouslySetInnerHTML onto a complex component.

Answer (score 3):

you have to close the html tag short hand if there aren't inner HTML

```
<Alert dang...={} />
```

instead `<Alert></Alert>`

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue myself. 
When you are recursively rendering a component, you must separate out the part of the component where dangerouslySetInnerHTML is being used into another component and then use that component in the one you are recursively rendering.

Comment: do you have an example?

Comment: It was a while ago, but basically: If your jsx that is being rendered recursively uses dangerouslySetInnerHTML it will fail, instead, set the HTML for that component in another function outside the recursion but call it within it. For some reason this had worked for me.

Comment: @DanielRam, do you have an example you can share with us. It could definitely help me right now.